# How to send zip file to api

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core-5.0

how to send zip file (file.zip) to api in angular. no need to unzip file and then send api just send zip file to api

[image]

Comment: what happens when you (try to) send it that way? And could you please post code in **Text** format?

Comment: please include code, error messages, and other _text-based_ information ***as text***, not as screenshot. i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: zip is actually a FILE , here is the simple method to send a file  using httpClient 
  http://demo.dotnetawesome.com/Webapi/how-to-upload-files-in-aspnet-webapi-using-httpclient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `FormData` interface:

```
 let file=this.formName.value.imagesfiles[0];      //Store file response into file variable
```

For example:

```
let formdata= new FormData();
formdata.append('key_object',file,'filename.zip')  //Appends a new value onto an 
                                                   //existing key inside a FormData object
```

Then post:

```
return this.http.post(url,formdata)
```

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData).